# (REOPENED) Is my question salvageable

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, close-reasons

[How to determine the best way to give notice when manager is absent](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/94763/how-to-determine-the-best-way-to-give-notice-when-manager-is-absent)

Details aside, the main idea is about how and when it is necessary to give notice in person rather than over the phone/through email.  I changed the question from a request for specific advice to a more general request for information to consider.

I think the answers and comments here are well-written and could potentially be useful to other people besides me but I'm not sure if other changes are necessary first.

Comment: VTRO two more votes required (3 of 5) as of this comment

Comment: @Joe according to the SE model, questions and answers are supposed to be broadly useful to the public. Even if the OP got all the answers *they* needed, someone else might have an answer that would be useful to someone else.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere A question being closed (as anything other than a duplicate) is a signal that it's not appropriate for the site. If it is appropriate for the site, it should not be closed, regardless of how sufficient the answers are (even questions or answers that do nothing but gather non-constructive answers or comments should not be closed, but possibly rather protected or locked). SE firmly supports anyone being able to contribute an answer or comment no matter how old the question is (essentially duplicating other answers is a separate issue that should be handled with voting).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Also, whether or not anyone would be able to provide another useful answer to any given question very much comes down to opinion or time - I don't think we should be preventing answers simply because we can't imagine any new answers being useful.

Comment: @dukeling I was under the impression that closed questions eventually got deleted or at least hidden from the public. Is this not correct?

Comment: @AffableAmbler Not in general and automatically, no. Automatic deletion is reserved for generally "meh" or unpopular questions (score 0 or less)
 - [here are the exact criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/206447). Manual deletion can be done by (3?) high reputation users on closed questions after like a week or something (or right away if the question has a lot of downvotes). Closed questions that aren't deleted are still visible to the public and can show up in Google search results. Very negatively scoring questions (open or closed) may be hidden, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question has been reopened now.